# How to send BUSD with metamask/web3.js

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask

I have two coins in binance testnet:

[image]

I can send default main coins (BNB) to another account:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
   from: account,
   to: '0x64123c0c6cc87a7b96c498D584Db17c6cA55eD6F',
   value: '1000000',
}, function (err, transactionHash) {
                    
});
```

But i don't know how to send other coins (USDT or BUSD).

Also i can check current amount of coins, but only for BNB:

```
const balance = await this.web3.eth.getBalance(account);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you transfer tokens, you interact with the token contract invoking its `transfer()` function.

Same goes for the token balance - you can get the user token balance by querying the token contract's `balanceOf()` function.

These functions are specified in the [ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) standard, so each token contract following the standard implements them.

```
const usdtContract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(abiJson, contractAddress);

// sends a transaction from the `sender` address
// containing the `data` field specifying that you want to execute
// the `transfer()` function, passing it the `recipient` and `amount` arguments
await usdtContract.methods.transfer(recipient, amount).send({from: sender});

// performs a gas-free read-only call, invoking the `balanceOf()` function of the contract
await usdtContract.methods.balanceOf(holder).call();
```

Comment: Please does this solution still work? I'm having the same issue using `window.ethereum`

Comment: @codervine Yes, the solution is still valid. The same issue means sending native tokens instead of ERC20? Then you can use this answer to solve it. If it's another issue, please search for an existing question/answer or if it hasn't been solved here on SO, please post a separate question with steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I found this answer very useful. But in my own case, it neither shows an error nor open the Metamask window for the transaction. I use `^1.7.3`.  Please do all contract in a chain have the same `abiJson`?

Comment: @codervine ABI JSON is specific to each contract - they are not all the same... Having said that, there are standardized contracts (for example ERC20) that implement the same functions and have the same ABI JSON. But as soon as a contract implements different functions, it has different ABI JSON.